# Bash quotes fun

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have code:

```
sudo_cmd="echo -e \\"$cmd\\" >> $CACHE_CONF"
echo "$sudo_cmd"
```

that prints string:

> echo -e "K1 = 'memcached://host/'\nK2
>   = 'memcached://host/'\n" >> /opt/settings.py

that works fine if I execute it in shell, here is result in *settings.py*:

```
K1 = 'memcached://host/'
K2 = 'memcached://host/'
```

However, when I execute this command via ssh:

```
ssh $user@$host "sudo sh -c \"$sudo_cmd\"
```

result in *settings.py* is different:

> K1 = memcached://host/nK2 =
>   memcached://host/n

Despite *-e* option for *echo*, newline does not work.

What I am doing wrong?

**Update:**

```
str="a\nb"
cat >> settings.py <<< "$str"
```

also does not work.

Comment: You're defining `$str` incorrectly.

Comment: I see. What is the difference between str="a\nb" and str=$'a\nb'? Second option works.

Comment: `$'...'` tells bash to interpret any escape codes in the quoted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with your escapes.

Presuming that

```
cmd="K1 = 'memcached://host/'\\nK2 = 'memcached://host/'\\n"
```

Then your sudo_cmd assignment needs to be

```
sudo_cmd="echo -e \\\"$cmd\\\" >> $CACHE_CONF"
```

Note the additional backslash escaping the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your \n again in the $cmd string, so it would be \n, then that would transfer through to the new string properly.

Comment: Can you give an example how to escape \n again?

Answer (score 0):

The `\` in `\n` is being processed by the shell that `ssh` is running in. Either use a heredoc/herestring with `cat`, or make the quoting more complex.

```
cmd=$'...\n...'
ssh ... "cat >> $CACHE_CONF" <<< "$cmd"
```

Comment: So how the ssh call shall look like? Following has rame result: ssh $user@$host "sudo sh -c \"cat >> $CACHE_CONF\" <<< \"$cmd\""

Comment: Same with ssh $user@$host "sudo cat >> $CACHE_CONF" <<< "$cmd"